# Unable to execute ST_GEOMFROMTEXT using executemany

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

Using python 3.5 and mysql 5.7.18 on Ubuntu 16.04, I am unable to use a ST_GEOMFROMTEXT function inside an executemany statement.

Using this code:

```
    print(query)
    print(add_vals[-1:])        
    zip_cursor.executemany(query, add_vals[-1:])
```

I get the following output:

```
INSERT INTO zipcodes (zipcode, name, area, pop, emp, emp_pay, households, location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);
[["'54517'", "'CLAM LAKE, WI'", 201.441702, 112, 10, 600, 59, "ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.145917 -90.930676)')"]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zip_parse.py", line 319, in <module>
    main()
  File "zip_parse.py", line 32, in main
    insert_data(zip_db, zip_cursor, data)
  File "zip_parse.py", line 160, in insert_data
    zip_cursor.executemany(query, add_vals[-1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 618, in executemany
    return self.execute(stmt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1416 (22003): Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

However, the passed statement seems to go in just fine when copied to a mysql command line:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO zipcodes (zipcode, name, area, pop, emp, emp_pay, households, location) VALUES ('54517','CLAM LAKE, WI',201.441702,112,10,600,59,ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.145917 -90.930676)'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

I have used the ST_GEOMFROMTEXT function extensively in the past, and I'm pretty confident that is the right way to add spatial data to a geometry field (the field 'location' has type 'POINT'). As demonstrated, it does not need quotes around it to work at the command line (which is often the sticking point in my experience).

Any ideas on why this is not working with execute many?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

```
import pymysql

point = 'POINT(18.16 -66.72)'
geojson = '{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.0]}'
```

the following snippet does not work:

```
"INSERT INTO `zip`(`id`, `zip`, `location`, `geometry`) VALUES (NULL,100, ST_PointFromText('%s'), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('%s') )"
qparams = (point, geojson)
cursor.execute(sql, qparams)
```

so the answer is to use it in this way:

```
"INSERT INTO `zip`(`id`, `zip`, `location`, `geometry`) VALUES (NULL,100, ST_PointFromText('"+ point +"'), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('"+ geojson +"') )"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the ST_GEOMFROMTEXT into the sql template as opposed to in the values array.  As in, instead of this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO zipcodes (zipcode, name, area, pop, emp, emp_pay, households, location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
```

you need this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO zipcodes (zipcode, name, area, pop, emp, emp_pay, households, location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(%s)"
```

and then in your add_vals list, instead of this string for "location":

```
"ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.145917 -90.930676)')"
```

you need this string:

```
"POINT(46.145917 -90.930676)"
```

Would be a good idea to add the SRID as the second argument to ST_GEOMFROMTEXT, too.